# How to register Celery task to specific worker?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I am developing web application in Python/Django, and I have several tasks which are running in celery.

I have to run task A one at a time so I have created worker with --concurrency=1 and routed task A to that worker using following command.

```
celery -A proj worker -Q A -c 1 -l INFO
```

Everything is working fine as this worker handle task A and other tasks are routed to default queue.

But, above worker return all task when I use `inspect` command to get registered task for worker. That is absolutely true because when I start worker, it displays all tasks of projects as registered task but handle only task A.

Following is the output of worker when I start it.

```
$ celery -A proj worker -Q A -c 1 -l INFO

 -------------- celery@pet_sms v4.0.2 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.8.10-040810-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2018-04-26 14:11:49
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x7f298a10d208
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> A exchange=A(direct) key=A


[tasks]
  . task_one
  . task_two
  . task_three
  . A
  . task_four
  . task_five
```

Is there any way to register specific task to the worker in celery?

Comment: So what is the problem u facing

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Notice following two parts in your worker log.

```
[queues]
  .> A exchange=A(direct) key=A

[tasks]
  . task_one
  . task_two
  . task_three
  . A
  . task_four
  . task_five
```

The first part `[queues]` shows the queues **your worker consumes**.

And it shows `A, exchange=A(direct), key=A`, indicating this worker only consumes tasks that are from the queue `A`. Which is exactly what you want. And you were achieving this effect because you specified `-Q A` when you started the worker by the command `$ celery -A proj worker -Q A -c 1 -l INFO`.

The second part `[tasks]` shows all the registered tasks of **this app**.

Though other tasks such as `task_one`  `task_five` are all registered, since these tasks do not go into queue `A`, therefore this worker does not consume the tasks `task_one`  `task_five`.