# Celery with Redis broker and multiple queues: all tasks are registered to each queue

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am using celery with Django and redis as the broker. I'm trying to setup two queues: `default` and `other`. My tasks are working, but the settings I have configured are not working as I am expecting them to work.

I'm having two related issues:

1. **celery tasks are not respecting the `task_routes` setting (see below).**
2. **all of the celery tasks (no matter how they are defined) are registered to each of the two queues when they are started**

Here's repo that contains all of the code. You can run the example locally with docker and docker-compose by running `docker-compose up`:

https://gitlab.com/verbose-equals-true/digital-ocean-docker-swarm

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

1. the celery app definition file
2. task definitions/declarations
3. commands to start workers

celery app definition:

```py
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

from kombu import Exchange, Queue

CELERY_QUEUE_DEFAULT = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUE_OTHER = 'other'

app = Celery('backend')
app.conf["broker_url"] = f"redis://{settings.REDIS_SERVICE_HOST}:6379/1"
app.conf["result_backend"] = f"redis://{settings.REDIS_SERVICE_HOST}:6379/2"
app.conf["accpet_content"] = ['application/json']
app.conf["task_serializer"] = 'json'
app.conf["result_serializer"] = 'json'
app.conf["task_acks_late"] = True
app.conf["task_default_queue"] = CELERY_QUEUE_DEFAULT
app.conf["worker_send_task_events"] = True
app.conf["worker_prefetch_multiplier"] = 1
app.conf["task_queues"] = (
    Queue(
        CELERY_QUEUE_DEFAULT,
        Exchange(CELERY_QUEUE_DEFAULT),
        routing_key=CELERY_QUEUE_DEFAULT,
    ),
    Queue(
        CELERY_QUEUE_OTHER,
        Exchange(CELERY_QUEUE_OTHER),
        routing_key=CELERY_QUEUE_OTHER,
    ),
)
app.conf["task_routes"] = {
    'backend.core.tasks.debug_task': {
        'queue': 'default',
        'routing_key': 'default',
        'exchange': 'default',
    },
    'backend.core.tasks.debug_task_other': {
        'queue': 'other',
        'routing_key': 'other',
        'exchange': 'other',
    },
}
app.conf["task_default_exchange_type"] = 'direct'

app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Task definitions (defined in a file called `tasks.py` in an app called `core`:

```py
import time

import celery

# from backend import celery_app as app
# from celery import shared_task
from celery.task import task
from django.conf import settings

# @celery.task <-- I have seen these decorators in other example
# @app.task <-- neither of these result in the tasks being sent to the correct queue
# @shared_task
@task(queue="default", exchange="default")
def debug_task():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "Task is done."


@task(queue="other", exchange="other")
def debug_task_other():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "Task is done for other queue."
```

Here's how I'm starting my workers in `docker-compose` locally:

```yaml
  celery:
    <<: *backend
    container_name: celery
    command:
      - "watchmedo"
      - "auto-restart"
      - "--directory=./"
      - "--pattern=*.py"
      - "--recursive"
      - "--"
      - "celery"
      - "worker"
      - "--app=backend.celery_app:app"
      - "-Q"
      - "default"
      - "--concurrency=1"
      - "--loglevel=INFO"
    ports: []

  celery_other:
    <<: *backend
    container_name: celery_other
    command:
      - "watchmedo"
      - "auto-restart"
      - "--directory=./"
      - "--pattern=*.py"
      - "--recursive"
      - "--"
      - "celery"
      - "worker"
      - "--app=backend.celery_app:app"
      - "-Q"
      - "other"
      - "--concurrency=1"
      - "--loglevel=INFO"
    ports: []
```

Here are the logs from `docker-compose` that show that the two tasks are both registered to each worker:

```
celery             |  
celery             |  -------------- celery@c8f0ed3f97df v4.4.7 (cliffs)
celery             | --- ***** ----- 
celery             | -- ******* ---- Linux-4.15.0-112-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2020-08-21 20:35:47
celery             | - *** --- * --- 
celery             | - ** ---------- [config]
celery             | - ** ---------- .> app:         backend:0x7fb327c2e6a0
celery             | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/1
celery             | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/2
celery             | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
celery             | -- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
celery             | --- ***** ----- 
celery             |  -------------- [queues]
celery             |                 .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
celery             |                 
celery             | 
celery             | [tasks]
celery             |   . core.tasks.debug_task
celery             |   . core.tasks.debug_task_other
celery             | 
celery_other       |  
celery_other       |  -------------- celery@3dd99b1ed32e v4.4.7 (cliffs)
celery_other       | --- ***** ----- 
celery_other       | -- ******* ---- Linux-4.15.0-112-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5 2020-08-21 20:35:47
celery_other       | - *** --- * --- 
celery_other       | - ** ---------- [config]
celery_other       | - ** ---------- .> app:         backend:0x7f54fa89e6a0
celery_other       | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/1
celery_other       | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/2
celery_other       | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
celery_other       | -- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
celery_other       | --- ***** ----- 
celery_other       |  -------------- [queues]
celery_other       |                 .> other            exchange=other(direct) key=other
celery_other       |                 
celery_other       | 
celery_other       | [tasks]
celery_other       |   . core.tasks.debug_task
celery_other       |   . core.tasks.debug_task_other
```

I was thinking that defining `task_routes` would mean that I don't have to specify the tasks's queue in the task decorator. If I don't specify the queue, the tasks are all picked up by the default worker.

If it helps, here is my Django directory structure:

```
tree -L 3 backend
backend
├── backend
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery_app.py <- this is where I define my celery app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── development.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── production.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py <- this is where I define the tasks shown above
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── docker
│   ├── Dockerfile.dev
│   └── Dockerfile.prod
├── manage.py
└── requirements
    ├── base.txt
    ├── dev.txt
    └── test.txt
```

Here's another related SO question from a few years ago that was never answered: [Celery tasks registering in multiple queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203203/celery-tasks-registering-in-multiple-queues)

Here's a link to the same issue that I raised on the celery/celery repo on GitHub: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6309

I have tried to follow the `Routing Tasks` page from the celery documentation to get everything setup correctly: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html

Edit:

I was mistaken about the output of celery worker process. The listed `[tasks]` refer to **all tasks for the celery app**, not the tasks that should be processed by that worker (which is what I assumed it meant). This SO post explains: [How to register Celery task to specific worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040495/how-to-register-celery-task-to-specific-worker), so it makes sense that that all tasks are listed in the output of both workers in `[tasks]`. This solves the 2nd issue I listed above.

Also I resolved the first issue by switching to using namespaced celery settings in Django settings, I may have also had something misconfigured. The celery tasks are now routed correctly and if the route is not specified in `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES` then it is routed to the default queue.

Comment: The tasks are not prefixed with “backend.”, you can see the task names/paths in the celery log

Comment: OK, I'll try adding this prefix @IainShelvington

Comment: Actually, @IainShelvington how can I add this prefix? Should I change the `task_routes` to match `backend.core.tasks.debug_task`?

Comment: Remove “backend.” from task_routes

Comment: I just tried this again, it still registers both tasks to both queues/workers.

Comment: I don't think the `task_routes` setting is being used at all, I can set it to be any value and it doesn't change how the tasks are registered

Comment: just checking out, did you try to send tasks and see what worker takes them

Comment: @iklinac Yes, `debug_task.delay()` and `debug_task_other.delay()` will send the task to the correct queue with the settings I currently have (defining the task with `@task(queue="other", exchange="other")`). My question is: should I need to do this if I have defined `task_routes`? If I don't specify the queue in the @task decorator, the tasks are both sent to the default queue, but I thought that `task_routes` should be able to handle routing tasks to the correct queue in a centralized place (`celery_app.py` where I have defined `task_routes`).

Comment: I am using celery(celery==4.4.7) routes with flask. It works fine. Only difference i can see in your log is that when worker loaded it shows "core.task.fn" registers. But you have "backend.core.task.fn" in the config. Just match both of them and see if that works. For me it shows full path from the project name.

Comment: Hi @Durai , so to confirm if you have two queues that only register tasks as defined in task_routes? I have tried changing the paths in several different ways, I have also tried providing a name in the task decorator and routing this way. Nothing seems to works, and there are a few other threads with a similar issue and no resolution other than setting the queue in the task decorator

Comment: Yes, @briancaffey. I even tried your example to check it out. It works as expected to me. I had small poc did earlier to check couple of things. I have tested routes like yours. It works fine. You can take a look at it. I am using flask though. https://github.com/dduraipandian/celery_proj

Comment: Hi @Durai thanks for trying my example. I updated my question with a link to a repo that should more accurately reproduce my issue I'm having. I saw your flask example, thank you for sharing. It does look very similar to what I have in my project. You can reproduce the project locally with docker if that helps. I also added a bounty to the question.

Comment: @briancaffey Can you share the version of Celery that you are using?

Comment: Sure @DevangPadhiyar you can see in the logs I posted that I'm using `v4.4.7 (cliffs)`

Comment: Maybe second issue is due to you have setting app.conf["task_default_queue"] = CELERY_QUEUE_DEFAULT and if one worker is busy task somehow passes to another.

Answer (score 0):

To Solve Your First Issue, Here You Go.

In Order To Use The Settings You Provide With Celery, You Need To Use `celery.update(__all__)` or if you only want to update your settings, you should do `celery.update(settings)`.

Feel free to comment if you need more help.